# How to Mount Guest DOS OS with HOST OS.?

Tags: windows, virtualbox, virtual-machine, ms-dos

I am newbie to VM concept. actually i have installed DOS6.22 under virtualbox and using 32bit windows 7 OS as HOST Operating System, now i want to copy some folders/files from HOST OS to DOS6.22 Guest OS. how can i copy.?

Comment: have you tried vex's link?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to install the network protocols in your DOS VM so it can be accessible from your host (and vice versa).

Take a look at this tutorial :

https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Sharing_files_with_DOS